# How to share a VPN network with a Vagrant VM?

Tags: networking, vagrant

I'm testing a recipe using chef kitchen. My recipe needs to download a docker image from an intranet repository. My workstation has access to this repository because I'm under vpn but the kitchen vm does not seems to have access (if I login in the vm I cannot resolve the address). In the target node this would not be a problem, as it will be on the same network, but so far I cannot test the recipes within the kitchen.

I tried to use the following configuration in the .kitchen.yml without success:

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
   - ["public_network"]
```

How can I share the same network between the host and the vm?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: Getting Vagrant tun/tap networks to work with a VPN is difficult bordering on impossible. You'll have to dive way in to the details of your VPNs virtual networking setup and see how it works. I would just store the file you need somewhere locally.

Comment: Also removing the Chef tag as this is only related to Vagrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host node is on the VPN then the VM should be able to access the same resources. I've run into this in the past and noticed I could hit the IP directly - which means it is DNS. Try adding `natdnshostresolver1` to your `.kitchen.yml`.

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  customize:
    natdnshostresolver1: "on"
```